# Recyclerview data appear again after deleting

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `recyclerview`. In its `item layout` , I have a plus button . If user click on that button it will become minus and new layout will added below it . If user click on minus it will remove from `recyclerview` as well as from the `dataset` .

**Problem is :**

When user click minus it removes properly from both `recyclerview` and `dataset` but on adding new layout it appears with old data again . I make sure that it deletes from `dataset` but still appears again.

**My Adapter Code:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {       
        holder.img_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {           

                if (if it is plus) {

                   holder.img_delete.setImageResource(set minus drawable);


                    MyModel model = new MyModel();                 
                    model.setPrice("");

                    data.add(model);

                    notifyItemInserted(position+1); //+1 Because first time im adding one data manually in onCreate to set adapter

                } else {

                    data.remove(position);

                    notifyItemRemoved(position);

                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: in else part, for now can you  use notifyDataSetChanged() after removing, be aware notifyDataSetChanaged refreshes whole, so a bit overhead

Comment: @notTdar  so `notifyItemRemoved`  causing problem ?

Comment: Use `getAdapterPosition()` instead of the position. try it and let me know.

Comment: well technically it should not cause any issue, but sometimes happens, did you test with above, or use notifyItemRangeChanged(), motifyItemChanged

Comment: @notTdar `notifyDataSetChanaged` is not working . it refresh all layout . for `notifyItemRangeChanged(), motifyItemChanged` i'm trying and let you know

Comment: @Jaymin ok ... i'm on it .using `holder.getAdapterPosition()`

Comment: @Jay333, Is your issue fixed?

Comment: @Jaymin no  i'm testing

Comment: @Jay333, Okay let me know your output.

Comment: I think you need to create one method in adapter for remove the data and that method should be called in your activity .

Comment: @Jaymin none of them worked . and after debug i found that . old data is not coming from `dataset` but coming from view . on click of plus button adapter just generate that old view again . so whatever i wrote in my old view apear again . is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @notTdar  please go through my above comment .